# preg_match_all() get a number from a string

Tags: php, foreach, numbers, preg-match-all

how works preg_match_all()?

I want to get a number from a string:

eg: I have the result:

> (62)

And I want just the number. And want to do that to several strings.
That's the try I did:

```
foreach($html2->find('small[class=menu-item__label__count]') as $aholder) {

$holderdes=$aholder->outertext;

preg_match_all('/([0-9]+)/',  $holderdes,$num);

echo $num.'<br>';
```

The return was "array array array array..."

Comment: var_dump($num) is your answer

Answer (score 0):

You should print `$num[0];`

```
foreach($num[0] as $pattern)
   // do something with $pattern
```

Also your regex looks wrong. If you want to match `(61)` you need to do (including parenthesis):

```
'/\(([0-9]+)\)/'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a String like `"(62)"`

Then you can use this:

```
<?php
    $str = '(62)';
    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(    
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 62
        )

)
```

Also if your trying to echo an Array(`$num`) an you get no `errors` turn Error Reporting on for debugging!

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_match returns an array as can be seen from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

if you want to see all the contents of the array use

```
var_dump( $sum );
```

If you just need the matched, you have to address that specific part.

Have a look for regex quick reference

- [abc] A single character: a, b or c
- [^abc] Any single character but
  a, b, or c
- [a-z] Any single character in the range a-z 
  -[a-zA-Z] Any single character in the range a-z or A-Z
- ^ Start of line
- $ End of line 
  -\A Start of string
- \z End of string
- .Any single character
- \s Any whitespace character
- \S Any non-whitespace character
- \d Any digit
- \D Any non-digit
- \w Any word character (letter, number, underscore)
- \W Any non-word character 
  -\b Any word boundary character
- (...) Capture everything enclosed
- (a|b) a or b
- a? Zero or one of a
- a* Zero or more of a
- a+ One or more of a
- a{3} Exactly 3 of a
- a{3,} 3 or more of a
- a{3,6} Between 3 and 6 of a

Answer (score 0):

This function is perfectly [explained](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) on php.net

Look at this very simple example that extracts numbers from an array of strings:

```
<?php
$strings = array ("fHzZGh4JMyfpc5visCC3q1a1ICBLWXnmfxoRa70S9HXHjBSVI4",
    "1LRWmzTQBErP6kIqXRLMgzWoVdOJKrLpUbL99sZ3XdtscAvydG",
    "5OMbG1hFMrTkMeThw64E80QqfLvxbZjo3tlsVzeJiDCDAn4D6C",
    "lrYFqKKtarRHfteYHUDx4KAEjssvs12Ix5u3YGQKATQBxtqAhn",
    "W3a3n0jzXtM2l5i8tOVnxPbBeGAz0ChzDQ6qhReQkdHTQ4sLmz");
$nums = array ();
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    preg_match_all('/\d+/', $string, $matches);
    $nums[] = $matches;
}

print_r($nums);
```

This is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 5
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => 1
                    [4] => 1
                    [5] => 70
                    [6] => 9
                    [7] => 4
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 6
                    [2] => 99
                    [3] => 3
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 64
                    [3] => 80
                    [4] => 3
                    [5] => 4
                    [6] => 6
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 12
                    [2] => 5
                    [3] => 3
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 2
                    [4] => 5
                    [5] => 8
                    [6] => 0
                    [7] => 6
                    [8] => 4
                )

        )

)
```